# After migrating to spring boot 2.7.12 to 3.0.1, @Interface didn't get instantiated

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have modified the spring boot starter parent version from 2.7.12 to  3.0.1 version.
I am able to build the application ,While starting the server getting the issue as below.

> Description: Field testRepository in TestService required a bean of
> type 'com.hp.ops.wander.framework.service.Repository' that could not
> be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.hp.ops.wander.framework.service.Repository' in your
> configuration. ,threadName:main,class:LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter

Can anyone please suggest a fix/workaround for this issue ?